# CheckBoxPreference with additional Button?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'd like to show an additional button in a `CheckBoxPreference`. I've managed this by subclassing `CheckBoxPreference` and a custom layout (using [this](https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/515681) code as a basis). However, I struggle to add an `OnClickListener`to this button in my `PreferenceActivity`. I've tried using a global `OnClickListener`-variable in the class extending `CheckBoxPreference` as well as adding a `getView()`-method to the `PreferenceActivity` that is supposed to return the Preference's view (to be able to use `findViewById(R.id.my_button)`, but both approaches don't work :-(.

Comment: In the example `findViewById` is used within the `onBindView` method, why can't you use it there?

Comment: I don't know how to assign an onClickListener defined in the PreferenceActivity to the button in the custom preference class. I can define a *local* onClickListener fine in onBindView, but don't know how to do it across classes.

Comment: I assume you're able to access the `CheckBoxPreferenceSubclassWithButton`? Just as in the `setIcon` method in the example you've linked it should be possible to have an instance variable for the click listener (equivalent to `mIcon` in the example), then set that listener locally in `onBindView` and create a method `setListener` setting the listener instance variable and calling `notifyChanged`.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! I only missed the call to `notifyChanged`. Would you like to post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an instance variable for the click listener within your subclass of `CheckBoxPreference`, which holds the listener you wish to set. Create a setter for this variable, calling `notifyChanged()` after setting the value. This will cause the `onBindView` method to be called on listener changes.

Now you can use this variable from within `onBindView`, set your listener to the button's view there (`view.findViewById(R.id.yourbuttonid)`).